# Why is char[] on the stack but char * on the heap?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm very confused about what's happening. I always thought `char *` and `char []` were interchangable, but after looking at the memory addresses it seems `char *` allocates space in the heap, whereas `char []` is allocating memory on the stack.

```
char stack[] = "hello";
char *heap = "hello";

char *heap_string_malloc = malloc(5);
heap_string_malloc = "hello";

printf("Address of stack[0]: %p\n", stack);
printf("Address of heap[0]: %p\n", heap);
printf("Address of heap_string_malloc[0]: %p\n", heap_string_malloc);
```

Outputs the following:

```
Address of stack[0]: 0x7fff8b0b85b0
Address of heap[0]: 0x400760
Address of heap_string_malloc[0]: 0x400760
```

Does this mean that `char *` is dynamically allocated?

Further to my confusion, how come `malloc` is allocating the same memory address as what `char *heap` has already allocated? I'm not running any optimisation (simply `gcc file.c`).

Comment: `char *heap_string_malloc = malloc(5); heap_string_malloc = "hello";` is an insta-memory-leak. This isn't Java. Consider this: `int a=5; a=6;` Where did the 5 go?

Comment: Arrays and pointers are *NOT* the same thing.

Comment: `"hello"` also type `char []`. But a `char *` can very well point to it.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Not in the global space, no it won't. In a local space of a function as an automatic it surly will compile nicely (and leak memory as described). The warning you received was likely from assigning a `const char[]` address to a non-const `char*` pointer, which recent C compilers will warn you about (my clang will, for example).

Comment: @WhozCraig: My mistake... I've checked my code, The error I got was even more silly (in a function `MyStruct **str_params` I attempted to assign something along the lines of `str_params->some_char_arr = some_char_ptr`) which, evidently didn't work

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Arrays are not pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html). What your program is doing, line by line, is

```
// Allocate 6 bytes in the stack and store "hello" in them
char stack[] = "hello";

// Allocate pointer on the stack and point it to a static, read-only buffer
// containing "hello"
char *heap = "hello";

// Malloc 5 bytes (which isn't enough to hold "hello" due to the NUL byte)
char *heap_string_malloc = malloc(5);

// Reset heap_string_malloc to point to a static buffer; memory leak!
heap_string_malloc = "hello";
```

The reason you're seeing the same pointer twice is because the compiler optimized away the second static buffer containing `"hello"`.

Comment: +1 And, of course it is perfectly reasonable that both static buffers containing `"hello"` are at the same address, so `heap_string_malloc` and `heap` could very well point to the same place.

Comment: if he hadn't `heap_string_malloc` to point to "hello", but instead to a different string "hola", would it still be a memory leak?

Comment: +1 That article drives home very well the simple fact that pointers are *variables* that *hold* addresses; arrays are variables that *are* addresses.

Comment: @user2018675 Of course, there's nothing magic about `"hello"` in C :)

Comment: @WhozCraig Surely you mean "arrays *have* addresses"?

Comment: @larsmans heh, I got it. I'll read the article you suggested. :-)

Comment: @larsmans nope, because so do pointers (have an address). An array's "value" *is* its address. A pointer's value is *an* address, but not *its* address. And I absolutely detest the functional term "decay", a word that appears in exactly zero places in the 600+ pages of the C standard. (atomic valuation not withstanding).

Comment: @user2018675 Yes, because he still hasnt got anything pointing to the memory allocated by malloc. I like to explain it using the analogy of dogs. I buy a dog from a shop and take him to the park with him connected to a lead (leash for you americans...) . While at the park, I let him off the lead, and connect the lead to somebody elses dog and go home. I still have a dog, but not my dog.  The "dog" is what malloc returned. The "lead", is heap_string_malloc. The other dog is "hello".

Comment: @larsmans Silly me about the 5 instead of 6 bytes. So if I wanted to put the string "world" into heap_string_malloc, would I have to use a function (I don't know what function does this). I'm guessing you can only dereference single characters, ie. `*heap_string_malloc++ = 'w', etc.` ?

Comment: @tgun926: `strcpy` and `memcpy` are the function for moving byte strings around.

Comment: if you allocate huge char[], it may move it out of the registers and into a pointer to the heap.

Answer (score 17):

When you do e.g.

```
char *heap = "hello";
```

the pointer `heap` actually does not point to the heap, it points to static data loaded together with the rest of program by the operating system loader. In fact, to be correct it should be

```
const char *heap = "hello";
```

as `heap` is pointing to a *constant* and *read-only* piece of memory.

---

Also, while arrays decays to (and can be used as) pointers, and pointers can be used with array syntax, they are *not* the same. The biggest difference being that for an array you can use e.g. `sizeof` to get the size in bytes of the actual array, while it's not possible for pointers.

---

And as a third thing, when you're doing

```
char *heap_string_malloc = malloc(5);
heap_string_malloc = "hello";
```

you have a *memory leak*, as you first assign something to `heap_string_malloc` but then directly afterward reassign `heap_string_malloc` to point to something completely different.

---

As for the reason you get the same address for both `heap` and `heap_string_malloc` it's because both points to the same literal string.

Answer (score 13):

String literals such as `"hello"` are stored in such a way that they are held over the lifetime of the program.  They are often stored in a separate data segment (distinct from the stack or heap) which may be read-only.

When you write

```
char stack[] = "hello";
```

you are creating a new `auto` ("stack") variable of type "6-element array of `char`" (size is taken from the length of the string literal), and the *contents* of the string literal `"hello"` are copied to it.

When you write

```
char *heap = "hello";
```

you are creating a new `auto` ("stack") variable of type "pointer to `char`", and the *address* of the string literal `"hello"` is copied to it.

Here's how it looks on my system:

```
       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
    "hello"       0x400b70   68   65   6c   6c    hell
                  0x400b74   6f   00   22   68    o."h

      stack 0x7fffb00c7620   68   65   6c   6c    hell
            0x7fffb00c7624   6f   00   00   00    o...

       heap 0x7fffb00c7618   70   0b   40   00    p.@.
            0x7fffb00c761c   00   00   00   00    ....

      *heap       0x400b70   68   65   6c   6c    hell
                  0x400b74   6f   00   22   68    o."h
```

As you can see, the string literal `"hello"` has its own storage, starting at address 0x400b70.  Both the `stack` ahd `heap` *variables* are created as `auto` ("stack") variables.  `stack` contains a *copy* of the contents of the string literal, while `heap` contains the *address* of the string literal.

Now, suppose I use `malloc` to allocate the memory for the string and assign the result to `heap`:

```
heap = malloc( sizeof *heap * strlen( "hello" + 1 ));
strcpy( heap, "hello" );
```

Now my memory map looks like the following:

```
       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
    "hello"       0x400b70   68   65   6c   6c    hell
                  0x400b74   6f   00   22   68    o."h

      stack 0x7fffb00c7620   68   65   6c   6c    hell
            0x7fffb00c7624   6f   00   00   00    o...

       heap 0x7fffb00c7618   10   10   50   00    ..P.
            0x7fffb00c761c   00   00   00   00    ....

      *heap       0x501010   68   65   6c   6c    hell
                  0x501014   6f   00   00   00    o...
```

The `heap` variable now contains a different address, which points to *yet another* 6-byte chunk of memory containing the string "hello".

**EDIT**

For byteofthat, here's the code I use to generate the above map:

dumper.h:

```
#ifndef DUMPER_H
#define DUMPER_H

/**
 * Dumps a memory map to the specified output stream
 *
 * Inputs:
 *
 *   names     - list of item names
 *   addrs     - list of addresses to different items
 *   lengths   - length of each item
 *   count     - number of items being dumped
 *   stream    - output destination
 *
 * Outputs: none
 * Returns: none
 */
void dumper(char **names, void **addrs, size_t *lengths, size_t count, FILE *stream);

#endif
```

dumper.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dumper.h"

/**
 * Dumps a memory map to the specified output stream
 *
 * Inputs:
 *
 *   names     - list of item names
 *   addrs     - list of addresses to different items
 *   lengths   - length of each item
 *   count     - number of items being dumped
 *   stream    - output destination
 *
 * Outputs: none
 * Returns: none
 */
void dumper(char **names, void **addrs, size_t *lengths, size_t count, FILE *stream)
{
  size_t i;
  int maxlen = 15;

  for ( size_t j = 0; j < count; j++ )
  {
    if (strlen(names[j]) > maxlen && strlen(names[j]) < 50)
      maxlen = strlen(names[j]);
  }

  fprintf(stream,"%*s%15s%5s%5s%5s%5s\n", maxlen, "Item", "Address", "00", "01",
    "02", "03");
  fprintf(stream,"%*s%15s%5s%5s%5s%5s\n", maxlen, "----", "-------", "--", "--",
    "--", "--");

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    size_t j;
    char *namefield = names[i];
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) addrs[i];
    for (j = 0; j < lengths[i]; j+=4)
    {
      size_t k;

      fprintf(stream,"%*.*s", maxlen, maxlen, namefield);
      fprintf(stream,"%15p", (void *) p);
      for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      {
        fprintf(stream,"%3s%02x", " ", p[k]);
      }
      fprintf(stream, "    ");
      for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      {
        if (isgraph(p[k]))
          fprintf(stream,"%c", p[k]);
        else
          fprintf(stream, ".");
      }
      fputc('\n', stream);
      namefield = " ";
      p += 4;
    }
    fputc('\n', stream);
  }
}
```

And an example of how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dumper.h"

int main(void)
{
  int x = 0;
  double y = 3.14159;
  char foo[] = "This is a test";

  void *addrs[] = {&x, &y, foo, "This is a test"};
  char *names[] = {"x", "y", "foo", "\"This is a test\""};
  size_t lengths[] = {sizeof x, sizeof y, sizeof foo, sizeof "This is a test"};

  dumper(names, addrs, lengths, 4, stdout);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does one print out this information from a program of their own?

Answer (score 1):

This creates an array on the stack, containing a copy of the static string "hello":

```
char stack[] = "hello";
```

This creates a pointer on the stack, containing the address of the static string "hello":

```
char *heap = "hello";
```

This creates a pointer on the stack, containing the address of a dynamically allocated buffer of 5 bytes:

```
char *heap_string_malloc = malloc(5);
```

But in all three cases, you put something on the stack. `char*` is not "on the heap". It is a pointer (on the stack) which points to something, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

"stack" is a static array of chars so it will be allocated in the stack and freed automatically once the function ends, because its size is known since its definition.
While "heap" and "heap_string_malloc" are both declared as pointers to char buffers and need to be allocated dynamicly with malloc in order to define the size of their content, that's why they will reside in the heap memory.
By doing:

```
char *heap = "hello";
```

and:

```
heap_string_malloc = "hello";
```

you are modifying the pointers them-self (with a static buffer value), not the content to which they're pointing. You should rather use memcpy to modify the memory pointed by the "heap_string_malloc" pointer with your data:

```
memcpy(heap_string_malloc, "hello", 5);
```